# Angular 2 and Up - Handling manual change detection when expression has changed

Tags: angular

Data in Angular flows one way down the component tree. If something were to change in a parent component due to a child component after the tree was check it would definitely cause the error.

```
Expression has changed after it was checked
```

One thing that I have read online is to redesign how data flows so that it flows one way. Another way is to do manual change detection such as calling on the class

```
ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

to handle updating the tree. I am just curious is there a correct way of handling these kind of issues that arises when an application grows big.

The question I have is mainly is it bad design to have to run manual change detection? Do we have to redesign our application.